# Extracting text that sits between two pairs of special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I am trying to extract a string from a sentence that is embedded within the HTML tags `<b></b>` that are also embedded within parenthesis ***(*** ***)***.

I can do this with the following code

```
const regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/

// fetches the string within parentheses 
let string = regExp.exec('This is some (<b>super cool</b>) text I have here')
// output = '<b>super cool</b>

// removes the html tags
let string2 = string.replace(/<[^>]*>?/gm, '')
// output = 'super cool'
```

The problem is I sometimes have sentences with multiple sets of parentheses. The code above will only extract the first instance of parentheses, and they may or may not be within the `<b></b>` tags

i.e., the string

```
This is (some) (<b>super cool</b>) text I have (here)
```

will return `some` using the same code above, but what I want is to return `super cool`

How can I traverse the entire string to extract only the text that sits within `(<b>` and `</b>)`?

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention (apologies), there may be text that comes in between the closing tag `</b>` and the closing parenthesis `)`. For example

`This is some (<b>super cool</b> groovy) text I have here`

Which adds a bit of complexity (otherwise I could use `split()` and `pop()`

Comment: Would it be ok to get what's between `(<b>` and `</b>)`?

Comment: That is exactly what I want, apologies if the question is confusing

Comment: What should it do with nesting? `<b>this <b>is cool</b></b>`

Comment: @Ben for this question we can assume there is no nesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this regExp instead: `/(?<=\(<b>)(.*?)(?=<\/b>\))/` which will capture everything between the first `(<b>` and `</b>)` encountered.

If you want to capture all instances, just add the global flag `/g` : `/(?<=\(<b>)(.*?)(?=<\/b>\))/g`

Also with this method you won't need to do a `string.replace()` afterwards, saving you another operation.

```
const regExp = /(?<=\(<b>)(.*?)(?=<\/b>\))/
const str = 'This is some (<b>super cool</b>) text I have here'

console.log(str.match(regExp)[0])
// --> super cool
```

**EDIT**: Following OP's edit, if some text can come between the closing tag `</b>` and the closing `)`, just change your regExp to: `/(?<=\(<b>)(.*?)(?=\))/`, which will capture everything between the first `(<b>` and `)` encountered.

But then you will also need to `string.replace('</b>', '')` to remove the closing `</b>` tag.

```
const regExp = /(?<=\(<b>)(.*?)(?=\))/
const str = 'This is some (<b>super cool</b> groovy) text I have here'

console.log(str.match(regExp)[0].replace('</b>', ''))
// --> super cool groovy
```

Comment: If he wants to make sure he gets all instances in the string and not just the first one he should be using the global flag with your answer, right?

Comment: I wasn't sure if he wanted only the first one or all of them. I've edited the answer to reflect your comment :)

Comment: Reread his post and it looks like I misunderstood what he was looking for. I think your first answer was great, but thanks for including that just in case.

Comment: This is 99% what I needed, thank you @Kendaros for the clean solution. However if there is text between the closing </b> tag and the closing parenthesis, this text is excluded from what I need returned (updated my question to include this info)

Comment: @KuraiBankusu I've updated my answer to your request.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me try like this instead of regex use split

```js
const string = 'This is (some) (<b>super cool</b>) text I have (here)';    
const str    = string.split('<b>').pop().split('</b>')[0];
console.log(str);
```

Comment: That does work fine @ayyappa, but if I have some text between the closing </b> tag and the closing parentheses, that text would not be included